# How to restrict a generic interface from accepting an unknown data type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a generic interface like this in typescript:

```
export interface IBaseDataResponse<T> extends ITraceData {
  attributes: T;
  id: string;
  type: string;
  relationships?: Record<string, string>;
}
```

and the usage would be like this:

```
export interface IIncluded {
  included: IBaseDataResponse<unknown>[]; // need to restrict unknown type from here
}
```

I need a way to restrict this interface from accepting an unknown data type like this:

```
IBaseDataResponse<unknown>
```

I tried this but not working properly:

```
type NotAcceptable<T> = T extends unknown ? never : T


interface IBaseDataResponse<T extends NotAcceptable<T>> {
  // Interface members...
}
```

When am using it like:

```
const validResponse: IBaseDataResponse<string> = {
  // Implementation...
};
```

it complains: `Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'never'.ts(2344)`

Here is full code what I want:

```
interface ITraceData {
  type: string;
}

interface IRelationship {
  type: string;
}

interface IBaseDataResponse<T> extends ITraceData {
  attributes: T;
  id: string;
  type: string;
  relationships?: Record<string, IRelationship>;
}

interface IIncluded {
  included: IBaseDataResponse<unknown>[];
}

class product {
  id: string = '';
  name: string = '';
}

const validResponse: IBaseDataResponse<product> = {
    attributes: {
      id:'1',
      name: 'alireza'
    },
    id: 'string',
    type: 'string',
};

// this should be restricted, want to restrict other developers from using unknown in IBaseDataResponse
const InValidResponse: IBaseDataResponse<unknown> = {
    attributes: {
      id:'1',
      name: 'alireza'
    },
    id: 'string',
    type: 'string',
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4SwOwFwUwJwGYEMDGNgEkAqdUwCJJRLADeAsAFCihQCeADjAFzADOUckA5gNxU0AvgNAiQkWIjyYASjAA2RMAHsIbABZgGZMbUYt2nHv2qhhpkLonxkaTACEkbAkSRy2DVc4A8WAHzAMAAesBAAJmyYOHiExDoWoERGAEYArrBsrFgmNOJhrBxcEHy6IPRMBUbFOblwCkpemgxsAPyscijKcGHehTwANLL1UCpqTX41IOY0VtA20hgYECjyqWEwYfG54Mur6-kOTi7E7p5qMN6pEADWEMoA7hB+ANoAupPA06IJK06RDHBlGFUigoFtcmADn1isAALzAADkCI+IAgSAAtgZodw4YjkbovpYfl4wQA3JDySGnLwGDCOZyxNwwDw07wAoEgqABeEUBI0JJcNIZVi87Y0SHMBEARgR-VKuTRmNYCIpYDqAC8kAj5VM5XzQBLEdjZTrgOUDAjjXqhB9dAB6O1mzSRDTKVLyTbJdB1PqgjaDe5IaBm5TAH1GUHAZRQdTwYDrUkKZRMOCRBCA9HAVJsHhZm53R47Q4M1zU866TpqMFLABqqrCZecrDpR0ZjYuV1uDyeuNFYoFYCFzJFprykpl1rFqIxFtVGq1psEk+2hstVW4Jv1ZX0yqtBN4QA)

Answer (score 2):

You basically solved your own question in the first edit, we just need to extend it to another interface/type, it can be an empty interface/type also.

this works!

```
interface IBaseDataResponse<T extends {}> extends ITraceData {
  attributes: T;
  id: string;
  type: string;
  relationships?: Record<string, IRelationship>;
}
```

this too works!

```
export interface ITraceDataModelValidations {
  id?: string;
}

interface IBaseDataResponse<T extends ITraceDataModelValidations> extends ITraceData {
  attributes: T;
  id: string;
  type: string;
  relationships?: Record<string, IRelationship>;
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUqIgETmOZAbwFgAoZZMATwAcIAuZAZzClAHMBucgX3PKhIsbGgBKEADb5gAexDMAFsFrFylGvSat2IbnwFkIAD1qyoYZEOjwkaTNjwEAsrIAmUgGpxJwNzPlmNQorNwB+bTZOHjJ+MkFwG1FUACE4Zlx8OAlmMwUIAB50ZBNIEDcgjCwkJzhXD0lvX38wOQUAPhLjMor7asyCYMp8KIAjAFdIZiZ0GMo-SN19EM1GFii9OeQoKQCFZVpmCOQJBHM3Ap1OABpxXdbAg-aYuIThWxRUVBAESXGPNxDKw-P4ApipdIDbIQXKBQrjEAAaxAsgA7iB2gBtAC6L0Mv3SQVoUHc4wQllIIQW6yWyAAvMgAOSMrYgOAAWzWVz09KZLIM8TIZwUlgAbj4-Dk8hlwWkMrUpXCCsTSeTOgzKZRhmAxpMYUxNVr5m4GIyAIyM67qI3INmcpiMiU7ABecEZ1sovCtIWNDu5HEtHqodDWjP9gdiMXIAHpo1RlEElLJxpJAaMUDsruSIG5bqi4OAqLJtjCouTkLIwIpoMgPKKpLJ6FAgjASezkONmJwO0iUejgWg5VDFflyMLWGgQE1JTDpWsIfKsiOMgUEci0RjeYbtbqpgag77zRGbbaOaGnRBXe6fcgvUHqWGNgHvUbVn6nxHeFwgA)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but all fields in `ITraceDataModelValidations` were optional and that's why I remove it to not confuse anyone and in that case it accept `unknown` as a generic type :(

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi what about the first option of extending empty type?

Comment: Then I already have a lint rule not using {} across the whole app